# Unable to determine the Mac OS X version on the targeted disk (-69831)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, permission, filesystem

I recently moved my home folder to another internal HDD on my MacbookPro (early 2011 OSX 10.9.4). I'm having an issue where in-app file dialogs cannot display my new home directory or its contents. I thought about trying to repair disk permissions but the option is greyed out in Disk Utility and I get the following error when trying to run it in terminal

```
sudo diskutil repairpermissions /Volumes/Data
Error starting permissions repair for disk1s2 Data: Unable to determine the Mac OS X version on the targeted disk (-69831)
```

I also tried rebooting into recovery mode and using the repair option in the resetpassword dialog but the /Volumes/Data disk does not appear, only the main boot volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/16/show-users-folder-mac-os-x-10-9-3/) resolved it:

```
sudo chflags nohidden /Users
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **Users & Groups** > **Advanced Options** options for your [moved user account](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23520271) is correct.

1. Launch **System Preferences.app**
2. Select **Users & Groups**
3. Unlock the panel
4. <kbd>Control</kbd> + Click on the moved account and select **Advanced Options…***
5. Update **Home directory:** to the correct, full, path to your moved home folder.

[image: System Preferences > Users & Groups on Mac OS X - some details redacted]

Comment: Hi. Yes, this is how I moved my home folder in the first place. Everything seemed to work except for this odd behaviour which prevents me from selecting the folder from within applications.

Comment: Good to hear you found a fix.